# How to Eliminate Namespace Local Name

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

I am trying to create an XML doc according to the following:

https://docs.safe.com/fme/html/FME_Desktop_Documentation/FME_ReadersWriters/gpxx/Feature_Types.htm

Just about everything works.  However, I am having a problem in the root tag.  I want a default namespace.  However, it puts in a local name.  I have tried various solutions, e.g. empty string, to no avail.

```
        XNamespace def = @"http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1";
        XNamespace gpxx = @"http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/GpxExtensions/v3";
        XNamespace xsi = @"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance";

        XDocument doc = new XDocument(
        new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", "no"),
        new XElement("gpx",
            new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "def", def),
            new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "gpxx", gpxx),
            new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "xsi", xsi),
            new XAttribute (xsi + "schemalocation", "http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1 http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1/gpx.xsd http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/GpxExtensions/v3 http://www8.garmin.com/xmlschemas/GpxExtensions/v3/GpxExtensionsv3.xsd"),
            new XElement("metadata",
            new XElement("time", DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime().ToString())
        )));
```

I get:

`<gpx xmlns:def="http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1" xmlns:gpxx="http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/GpxExtensions/v3" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemalocation="http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1 http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1/gpx.xsd http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/GpxExtensions/v3 http://www8.garmin.com/xmlschemas/GpxExtensions/v3/GpxExtensionsv3.xsd">
  <metadata>
    <time>2019-05-03 18:46:27</time>
  </metadata>`

What I want is:

`<gpx xmlns="http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1" xmlns:gpxx="http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/GpxExtensions/v3" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemalocation="http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1 http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1/gpx.xsd http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/GpxExtensions/v3 http://www8.garmin.com/xmlschemas/GpxExtensions/v3/GpxExtensionsv3.xsd">
  <metadata>
    <time>2019-05-03 18:46:27</time>
  </metadata>`

Comment: The net library wants the default namespace at the end of the list.  I usually just create a string of the root node and then use XDocument.Parse(string) so I don't have to deal with the Syntax.  The code is much easier to read.

Comment: Thanx.  That did the trick.  I just wonder why they can't handle default namespaces gracefully.

Comment: Do not know why Microsoft does what they do.